# Getting server certificates from https/ws server automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, websocket

I'm hosting a website on git pages that opens a video stream on certain clicks over a secure websocket (wss) using this library: github.com/websockets/ws. When connecting video from an http page over a simple websocket (ws) everything was fine, but I realized the github page will be hosted over https and firefox does not allow unsecured websocket connections over https, wss is required.

To do that I followed the steps on the websockets ws page and the websocket server is sort of "hiding" behind an https server that does the certificate handshake. The problem is this: If I use my web page normally and open the link that starts a wss connection to the video it doesn't work, the server doesn't know it exists. If I first visit the server directly via IP and port using an https://IP:999 link it retrieves the certs and from then on the website works indefinitely.

Is there a way to do this naturally that doesn't require me trying to visit a headless server to do the cert handshake? I just want to open a wss connection but the overhead of having to visit a server directly for certs seems a bit bizarre.

The server setup looks like this:

```
  const server = https.createServer({
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/cert.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/key.pem'),
}, function (req, res) {
    console.log(new Date() + ' ' +
    req.connection.remoteAddress + ' ' +
    req.method + ' ' + req.url);
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello foobarbackend\n");
    });
  this.wsServer = new ws.Server({
    server
  })
  this.wsServer.on("connection", (socket, request) => {
    return this.onSocketConnect(socket, request)
  })
  server.listen(9999, '0.0.0.0');
```

Once the certs are retrieved via https://:9999 I can then play videos no problem on that browser at wss://:9999, I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The question here is answered entirely by the world of SSL/TLS. The issue here was that secure browsers will pretty much silently reject WSS:// connections to servers with self signed certificates. My certificates were self signed.

This is why the user would have to navigate to the server IP directly over HTTPs first and then accept the warnings. From there it's business as usual.

What needed to be done was register a domain name for the IP the server was located on (Droplet). Then certbot was used to generate real certificates (key, cert) for the domain. I replaced the cert.pem and key.pem above with the true generated ones. Domain name can be anything like mywebsitewhatever.app.

Now on the client side you can open up a connection to wss://mywebsitewhatever.app:9999 and the browser will accept it automatically and things work. No warnings or navigation to a warning page to accept.